# Why can't I withdraw any BTC from MtGox?

Tags: mtgox

I have a balance of just 4 BTC at Mt Gox and when I try to withdraw them I get this message: **Your account is currently pending review, please visit https://mtgox.com/forms/verification**

What am I supposed to do about this?  Is anyone else having the same problem?

**EDIT** (cannot comment or answer my own question?): Yes I created the account using Tor, and their response says that's the reason.  @Stephen Gornick you are correct, the restriction is specified when creating the account.

Comment: You need to go to that URL and follow the instructions.  Your ID must be verified to conduct any business of any size on Mt Gox.  Try withdrawing 2 BTC

Comment: @Steve Rogers, did you by chance try to access your Mt. Gox account using Tor?  When signing up they expressly state conditions in which ID verification will be required.  Access via Tor is on of those conditions.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - I don't think this is true. 7 BTC is below the daily withdrawal limit for unverified users.

Comment: @ripper234 This may have been the case when BTC was worth less... 4 BTC 9 hours ago would have been worth just over 1K where most AML laws apply

Answer (score 2):

When Mt. Gox initiates the demand for verification your account is essentially frozen for withdrawals until you send in the required identification (color photo ID and whatever else they want) and your account gets verified.

The instructions from the link you provided will clearly state what is needed.

For example, it might state

> - VALID Photo ID Proof (Identity card, license, passport,...)
> - Residence Proof (utility bill, tax return, insurance,...)
>     ISSUED WITHIN 6 MONTHS

For the color photo ID, even a pic of the ID taken with a phone is usually sufficient.

Comment: It's worth noting that we have no real way to know the specific trigger to Mt. Gox verification request. Tor access is indeed one factor that triggers it, I don't know if there are more.